# How would someone benchmark io.open() in Python?

Tags: python, benchmarking

Let's say I want to see if reading a file using `os.open()` is actually faster than `io.open()`. I know that one returns a file descriptor and the other one returns an object, but the contents of a file can be read both ways (note that I'm interested in reading binary data (`b` or `os.O_BINARY`). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html is the usual way of doing these kind of microbenchmarks.

```
from timeit import timeit
timeit("f=os.open('testfile', os.O_RDONLY);os.read(f, 999);os.close(f)",
       setup="import os")
```

Should get you started. You may need to try with turning the garbage collector on and off and see if there's a difference too.  But that's all documented in the timeit docs.